# Filtering WP_Query based on wp_postmeta keys values

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

In the context of a Wordpress widget development, I use `WP_Query` this way:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'myType',
    'post_per_page' => $number,
    'showposts' => $number
);
$latest_myTypes = new WP_Query($args);
if ($latest_myTypes->have_posts()):
    global $post; //etc.
```

When a `myType` post is saved, it stores some values in the table `wp_postmeta`, in particular two keys: `day` (an integer) and `month` (a string).

As you can see, in the preceding code I get **all** the posts of type `myType`.

I need a different thing: since any single post contains *upcoming* events, I want to get all the posts where the date is equal or after the current date (so, `day` must be at least *today* **AND** the `month` should be at least *the current month*).

Is it possible to modify my `WP_Query` to filter the posts this way?

I've red about `meta_query` but I've not understood how to integrate a *meta query* to my current query, and even how to create the query itself.

In *pseudocode*, I should get all the posts `WHERE`:

```
day >= date("j")

    AND

date("n", strtotime(month)) >= date("n")
```

Can you help me?

*Update*: I know it would be much easier if I could store the Unix timestamp of an upcoming event date: problem is I inherited code from another developer and found that he used metaboxes to automatically save data. I couldn't find a way to alter his code to save day, month and year submitted by a user as a combined and unique key value, since he uses three different fields (it would be interesting if I could create a sort of *computed* field)

*Update*: I suppose I solved this way:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myType',
        'post_per_page' => $number,
        'showposts' => $number,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'month',  
                'value'     => array(date("F"),date("F", strtotime('+1 month'))),
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'day',  
                'value'     => date("j"),
                'compare'   => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'year',  
                'value'     => date("Y"),
                'compare'   => '='
            ),
        ),
    );
```

It is working fine. Any other comment, solution, suggestion, etc. is eventually appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'myType',
        'post_per_page' => $number,
        'showposts' => $number,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'month',  
                'value'     => array(date("F"),date("F", strtotime('+1 month'))),
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'day',  
                'value'     => date("j"),
                'compare'   => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'year',  
                'value'     => date("Y"),
                'compare'   => '='
            ),
        ),
    );
```